# ¿Cómo mostrar un menú en múltiples paginas JSP en Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, spring, spring-mvc

Estoy intentando crear un tienda online usando Spring MVC. Quiero mostrar en el menú una lista de categorías y subcategorías almacenada en base de datos en mas de una página (pág. Home, pág. Productos, etc).

En la controlador de la página Home obtengo la lista de categorías y subcategorías y las paso a la página home.

¿Tengo que escribir el código en cada controlador o hay una mejor manera?

Por favor, apreciaría mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando tienes funcionalidades que son transversales a toda la aplicación, una solución es crear una clase Controlador abstracta que tenga estos métodos implementados, y hacer que todos tus constroladores la extiendan.

Con los JSP puedes crear fragmentos y simplemente insertarlos, por ejemplo podrías crear un fichero `nav.jspf` y en cada página donde quieras mostrar un menú de navegación sólo tienes que incluirlo con

```
<%@include file="nav.jspf" %>
```